# sklearn: Get Distance from Point to Nearest Cluster

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I'm using clustering algorithms like `DBSCAN`.

It returns a 'cluster' called `-1` which are points that are not part of any cluster. For these points I want to determine the distance from it to the nearest cluster to get something like a metric for how abnormal this point is. Is this possible? Or are there any alternatives for this kind of metric?

Comment: How do you want to measure distance to a cluster? There are a lot of options: single linkage says the distance to a cluster is the distance to its closest member. Complete linkage says it's the distance to the farthest member. There's average linkage, Ward's linkage...what are you going for?

Comment: My first intuition says that ``single linkage`` sounds like a good metric and is what I had in mind. But good to know that there are different metrics, thanks for this.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to determine the distance of a noisy point to a nearest point of a cluster (since you use single linkage) right? If so you can calculate the euclidean distance between the noisy point and cluster points by [sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html). Euclidean distance should work well since it is also the most common distance metric that is used in DBSCAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer will depend on the linkage strategy you choose. I'll give the example of single linkage.

First, you can construct the distance matrix of your data.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
dist_matrix = pairwise_distances(X)
```

Then, you'll extract the nearest cluster:

```
for point in unclustered_points:
    distances = []
    for cluster in clusters:
        distance = dist_matrix[point, cluster].min()  # Single linkage
        distances.append(distance)
    print("The cluster for {} is {}".format(point, cluster)
```

EDIT: This *works*, but it's O(n^2) as noted by Anony-Mousse. Considering core points is a better idea because it cuts down on your work. In addition, it is somewhat similar to centroid linkage.

Comment: This is very slow, as it computes many distances that are not needed. Also, it uses O(n²) memory and will not work for larger data sets.

Answer (score 1):

To be closer to the intuition of DBSCAN you probably should only consider *core* points.

Put the core points into a nearest neighbor searcher. Then search for all noise points, use the cluster label of the nearest point.